# How to set readOnly on a jRate plugin's param after make a click on a star

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been a while thinkig on how to set de readOnly param to de jRate plugin after clicking on a star and i cant find the solution.

This is the code I've been working on:

```
$("#jRate").jRate({
    startColor: 'yellow',
    endColor: 'red',
    width: 17,
    height: 17,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    precision: 0,
    /* Show rating when mouse over*/
    onChange: function (rating ) {
        $('#rating ').text(" " + rating );
        readOnly: true;
    },
    /*set a click's behavior*/
    onSet: function (readOnly) {
        //$('#demo-onset-value').text("Selected Rating: " + rating);
        readOnly: true;
        alert(readOnly); // just only to view readOnly value
    }
});
```

I've tried to set param directly as you see, 
I've tried TO set a global viriable like var read = false, and then on "onSet" function set read = true and return that value, so finally set
readOnly: onSet();

Now way, I cant set readOnly variable after a click. Yes I can set only the variable readOnly: true, before onSet() function but this only make the stars disable.

This plug-in is to make a visual "stars" rating like: * * * * *

Regards !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this `rater.setReadOnly(true);`

```
var rater = $("#jRate").jRate({
  rating: 3,
  strokeColor: 'black',
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  onSet: function(rating) {
    rater.setReadOnly(true);
  }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/materasome/1/)

Comment: Grate answer !!!!! that was the exact way to do it. Thank you so much Dhiraj !!! I Love stack overflow :)

Comment: please mark it as answered so that others can benefit from it. Given that the jRate website doesn't have enough documentation regarding this.